# count and fractional frequency for all letters in words.txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the count and fractional frequency for all letters, excluding \n character, in 'words.txt' file. I've written following code segment

```py
FILENAME = 'words.txt'

fvar = open(FILENAME, 'r')  # open file for reading

bigline = fvar.read() # read ENTIRE file into single string
print("Number of characters is: %d" % len(bigline))

length_without_newlines = len(bigline) - bigline.count('\n')


ref_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

num_l = 0

for x in bigline:
    if x in ref_string:
        num_l += 1
print('Count of letter',x, 'is: ', num_l)
frac_freq  =  float(num_l)/float(length_without_newlines)

#This isn't working properly
```

Is it possible to iterate over ref_string and print count and fractional frequency of each letter, excluding newline character ; that is, the count of specific letter divided by the total number of letters in the file, not counting newlines? Since I am very new to python, It'll be great if someone can update the code for this function.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Comment: Thanks. I was asked to do it using ref_string. Also, I was not getting a consistent result in fractional frequency which is divide count of each letter/total letter and do it for all letters.

Comment: I suggest editing the title of the question, as it does not seem to match with the content.

Comment: _You were asked_ ... why don't you do your task then? Where is your approach trying to solve this? What is your specific problem beside not having any code that solves _your task_? Hint: use a dictionary. Or use a list of plenty of 0 and the positional relation with the string you were given and increment the correct position for each letter in your string.

Comment: I've used following logic. ref_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

num_l = 0

for x in bigline:
    if x in ref_string:
        num_l += 1
print('Count of letter',x, 'is: ', num_l)

Comment: But it is not working properly. Could you please suggest update.

Comment: I've updated my answer below, now it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example helps:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter('line')
total = sum(counter.values())
for letter, count in counter.items():
    print(f'Count of letter {letter} is: {count}')
    frac_freq = float(count)/float(total)
```